# CodeIgniter: Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this issue where I am posting a response into the controller, however it throws this error. This is the first time I am coming across this error.

Kindly find the code below:

```
    if (isset($this->input->post('responseCode'))) 
       {
         echo '<p><strong>Cardstream Response</strong></p>';
         echo '<pre>';
         print_r($this->input->post());
         echo '</pre>';
       }
```

It is pointing at this particular line `if (isset($this->input->post('responseCode')))`

This is a cardstream integration. Unfortunately I haven't found the library for cardstream in codeigniter, hence I am using the Core PHP code for the same.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try null !== instead of isset

Comment: You should always go and look up the documentation so when you ask yourself "What does this function/method return?" you will be enlightened and find the answer to the problem!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Tim and wolfgang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `isset()` on a method, which presumably returns a expression result. You cannot do that because `isset()` is only used on variables. Try checking if it's null instead:

```
if ($this->input->post('responseCode') !== null) {...
```

Or simply:

```
if ($this->input->post('responseCode')) {...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
if ($this->input->post('responseCode'))
```

instead `isset()` checking

Comment: Well that sorted that error. Sorry for the late reply. There were a couple more errors I needed to sort out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

you cant use isset on a function   you couldusse

```
if($this->input->post('responsecode'))
```

or `if(!empty($this->input->post('responsecode')))`